# passed dynamic method is always null

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to pass a dynamic method as a parameter to another method.
However, the passed method is always null. If I call the method directly, everything works fine.

I tried the process first with a given delegate as a parameter and secondly with the dynamic keyword, as seen below.

Can anybody help me out here?

I'm working with the SignalR Framework so, Clients.Caller is the dynamic object.

```
public void Dummy() {

        Clients.Caller.getChunk(new byte[] { 0x01 });               // I work fine!
        SendData(new byte[] { 0x01 }, Clients.Caller.getChunk);     // I don't?
    }

 private void SendData(byte[] bigData, dynamic targetFunction)
    {
        targetFunction(bigData); // targetFunction always null.
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried casting "getChunk" object into Action<byte[]>?
var targetFunction = (Action<byte[]>)Clients.Caller.getChunk;
and then invoke your SendData.

Comment: I'm assuming `getChunk` takes a `byte[]` parameter, couldn't you just change the `SendData` argument from `dynamic targetFunction` to `Action<byte[]> targetFunction`? This works for me, but I'm not familar with 'SignalR Framework' so I'm probably overlooking something.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you may have to instantiate the delegate to use or invoke it. I wrote this bit of sloppy code, but I hope it helps.

```
  class Program
{
    delegate void GetChunk(byte[] address);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Class1 class2 = new Class1();
        GetChunk del = new GetChunk(TheDelegate);
        SendData(new byte[] {0x01}, del);
    }

    public static void SendData(byte[] data, dynamic targetFunction)
    {
        targetFunction(data);
    }

    static void TheDelegate(byte[] chunk)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(chunk);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input.
However, the parameter 'targetFunction' is still null all the time, so dynamicInvokin won't have another effect.

Im actually trying to figure out why targetFunction (which is the getChunk method) is null, even thought I can use getChunk outside of this method).

Comment: It seems to me the culprit is in the instance of the delegate. Is it static? I just created this and it work just fine.

Comment: the function (getChunk) is actually defined on the clientside (via javascript) and SignalR is providing me the function during runtime. My knowledge is pretty limited about that case.

So what I actually believe is, that there is only a copy passed of my object, which does not have the dynamic created method.
I hope you know what Im talking about, my english feels pretty limited at that time.

Comment: Its null so that's telling me something with it working with a parameter. Just have to check to see why the passed parameter isn't getting the type off when it's passed.

Comment: Awe okay that explains some. So its acting like it is static or something. I wonder if it has a return. If it does, maybe try using var to get the instance into something to use later. JavaScript is loosely typed so it might work. Is SignalR an object that you can make calls off of?

Comment: Hi; SignalR is actually a Library from Microsoft for real-time web application (http://signalr.net/).

The fun thing ist, if I pass Clients.Caller (as dynamic), I can call Clients.Caller.getChunk(...) without anyproblems.
But passing the function directly as a delegate for example doesnt work.
And that's exaclty what I have to.

Comment: Ya you have to figure out a way to get an instance of that delegate to call off of or get a context that will work with dynamic. I haven't worked with SingalR, so you probably know more than I. I found this link though: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-net-client#clientmethodswithparmtypes

Comment: Thanks for the link, I feel like I lack of knowledge about dynamics in general.
I think it's better to read myself into this area and then get back to the work.

Answer (score 0):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  TestClass class2 = new TestClass();
  Action<byte[]> targetFunction = TheDelegate;
  SendData(new byte[] { 0x01 }, targetFunction);
}

public static void SendData(byte[] data, dynamic targetFunction)
{
  targetFunction(data);
}

private static void TheDelegate(byte[] chunk)
{
  Console.WriteLine(chunk[0]);
  Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: I am not sure this will work for you, but this way you can send an Action<YourParemeterHere> and it works when you call the target function. I just realized after posting this that you already have your delegate given to you. Can you not get the byte first, then wrap in in an Action and send it that way? Just a thought.